# Jquery tab show all tab at once, on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I using mvc 4 and i have trouble with JqueryUi, it always shows all tab at once.

**In my layout**

**Top**

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css","~/Content/themes/package/css","~/Content/themes/base/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

**Bottom**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/package")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

**In view**

```
    <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>  commodo</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>  tincidunt, dui sit </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id </p>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        });
    </script>
    }
```

script render html page no error.

Comment: make other tab divs display:none

Comment: Go to dev tools and check to make sure that jQuery UI is being pulled down in your bundle.

Comment: @VtoCorleone "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css"
"~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
"~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css" etc,it already include.

Comment: Pratik Joshi, but then it always show only visible div

Comment: Ok, I have found out that, it seem to be cause of nucget package update javascript,css. I remove all and make it default. Now it work, thanks all.